# Return Partial View After Http Post Request Failed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When Submit Action is invoked after Ajax Post Request. It returns the error method with value "Bad Request". Why it is not successful ? How to resolve this ?

The Ajax Request:

```
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Test"))
    {
        <span>
            Price: @Html.TextBox("Price", string.Empty)
        </span>

        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="test" />
    }
</p>

<div id="testPost">

</div>

        @section Scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#submit').on("click", function () {

                    var form = $(this).parent("form");

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: form.attr('action'),
                        data: form.serialize()
                    })
                        .success(function (html) {

                            $('#testPost').replaceWith(html);

                            alert("Success");
                        })
                        .error(function () {
                            alert("Bad Request");
                        });

                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
        }
```

Submit Action:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Submit(Auction auction)
        {
            return PartialView("_CurrentPrice",auction);
        }
```

Partial View:

```
<p class="current-price">
    <h2>ACTIVE HERE</h2>
</p>
```

Comment: Check you expected and sending values , remember `form.serialize()` returns a string

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved. The partial view was not in the Shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let us know whether this is working..

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/test/submit",
                    data: form.serialize()
                })
```

NOTE: There should be a controlled named "TestController" and an action named "Submit", which you already have...

If this works, put a console.log (form.attr("action")) and see what is the return value...

Comment: Tried with this code but again it fails. It returns the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should use firebug and check object `arguments[0]` and property `arguments[0].responseText` into error method. It helps to know the reason for which the server returned an error.

Or try -

```
.error(function () {
$.('body').html(arguments[0].responseText);
}
```

And check the name Partial View. It must be equal "_CurrentPrice"